# CSS issue to remove extra space

Tags: html, css

I you can see on the picture, the text is not aligned vertically in the DIV, there's more space under the text. How can I fix this? The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/w4HWn/ Thanks

[image]

Comment: I think you have to expand your description of the problem.

Comment: @Greg: If it was the only the `<br>` issue then @reisio answered first. If however, true vertical centering with a height was useful then my answer would work.

Comment: If you remove the br's, Moin, they *are* vertically centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `br` elements are almost certainly inappropriate as used.  Assuming those are nav items, you should also be [using a `ul`](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).  The spans are probably superfluous.

Comment: 'almost certainly' and assumptions don't make it an accurate answer. `<br>`'s are valid markup and they may not be nav elements :)

Comment: No indeed they do not, but the poster finding that it is does. :p br's are valid markup, and using them as he did was wrong.  They may not be nav elements (to him), which is why I used the 'Assuming'. :p

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `padding` on the top and bottom
2. Remove the `<br>`'s
3. Give the container a fixed `height` of lets say `100px`
4. Now give the container a `line-height` that is the same as above, i.e. `100px`

See updated **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4HWn/3/)**

Comment: Only 2 is relevant, and I posted it before you did. :p

Comment: @reisio: Incorrect. 3 and 4 give you vertical centering of text. Also posting before someone else doesn't give you the right to freely downvote. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: No, the right to freely downvote gives me the right.  They are misaligned solely because of superfluous br elements, yet that is only one (and not the first) of four items you mention.

Comment: @reisio: Ah, yes! you're right. We can freely downvote :) <sarcasm>

Comment: Obviously? How else do you imagine I downvoted your answer. :p

Answer (score 0):

Actually noticed that the `<br>`'s were added inadvertently - I removed them and it' OK now

Comment: If you noticed that because of the people here pointing it out, you're supposed to select an answer.